# python program for wifi connected devices

Tags: python

I saw this interesting idea from Kalle Hallden's [video](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=imN-vhi5ZWQ&t=82s). It is about alerting you when someone's IP connects to the network

```
import sys
import subprocess
import os
from decouple import config

IP_NETWORK = config('IP_NETWORK')
IP_DEVICE = config('IP_DEVICE')

proc = subprocess.Popen(["ping", IP_NETWORK],stdout=subprocess.PIPE)
while True:
  line = proc.stdout.readline()
  if not line:
    break
  #the real code does filtering here
  connected_ip = line.decode('utf-8').split()[3]

  if connected_ip == IP_DEVICE:
      subprocess.Popen(["say", "Linnea just connected to the network"])
```

**Error**

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
  
File "C:\Users\utkar\Downloads\net-listen.py", line 6, in <module>
    IP_NETWORK = config('IP_NETWORK')
  
File "C:\Users\utkar\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python38-32\lib\site-packages\decouple.py", line 199, in __call__
    return self.config(*args, **kwargs)
  
File "C:\Users\utkar\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python38-32\lib\site-packages\decouple.py", line 83, in __call__
    return self.get(*args, **kwargs)
  
File "C:\Users\utkar\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python38-32\lib\site-packages\decouple.py", line 68, in get
    
raise UndefinedValueError('{} not found. Declare it as envvar or define a default value.'.format(option))
decouple.UndefinedValueError: IP_NETWORK not found. Declare it as envvar or define a default value.


Process returned 1 (0x1)        execution time : 0.150 s
Press any key to continue . . .
```

Comment: What is your question?

Comment: are you already store the IP_NETWORK and IP_DEVICE at .ini or .env? See https://pypi.org/project/python-decouple/

Answer (score 0):

Seems like you forgot to setup a settings.ini. It should look something like this:

```
[settings]
IP_Network=YOUR NETWORK IP
IP_DEVICE=YOUR DEVICE IP
```